# Upload video to YouTube fully automated using YouTube Data API (v3)

Tags: .net, youtube, google-api

It is possible to upload a video to YouTube using the YouTube Data API (v3). Apparently, [it is not supported to upload a video using a Service Account](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5370). A Service Account would be the natural way to implement a programmatic fully unattended video upload. Trying a Service Account results in the dreaded [`youtubeSignupRequired`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth) error.

What is the easiest way to:

- Upload a video
- Obtain the video ID
- Do this programmatically and in a fully automated way
- No human interaction (except one time developer interaction)
- Suitable for use in an ASP.NET MVC web app
- The video is a file on the server's disk

?

Using one of the other authorization flows that require user interaction does not seem possible under these constraints.

Comment: You could simulate opening a browser and save the click positions to upload the video?

Comment: That's pretty hard to make reliable. It can also stop working anytime when the web site changes. It would work in principle.